# Multiple jQuery :contains() args not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, filter

I'm trying to pass variable values into :contains() arguments, and I can't multiple args to work.

Here's what I mean:

To do multiple :contains() filters, you use `$("li:contains('arg1'):contains('arg2')").etc();`

This means that only `li`s with *both* `arg1` and `arg2` will match this search.

Okay, so what I'm trying to do is:

```
var styleQuery = $("td:contains("+ styleOption + "):contains("+ glassOption +")");
```

No luck.

```
var styleQuery = $("td:contains("+ styleOption + ")");
```

works perfectly, but the second variable search doesn't.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

**EDIT**

Actually, I fixed some types and am now getting this returned as the selector via the console:

```
tr:contains(Sliding Patio Doors):contains(Double Glazed LoE 180)
```

So the :contains() filter is working now, but I'm still not able to get my code to work. Thanks for the help though! Still stumped but this specific issue is at rest.

Comment: what are `styleOption` and `glassOption`? Multiple `:contains()` work fine in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zz9uN/, so there must be something wonky with your variables.

Comment: Actually, I fixed some types and am now getting this returned as the selector via the console:

`tr:contains(Sliding Patio Doors):contains(Double Glazed LoE 180)`

So the :contains() filter is working now, but I'm still not able to get my code to work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the single-quotes:

```
var styleQuery = $("td:contains('"+ styleOption + "'):contains('"+ glassOption +"')");
```

Comment: god, jquery just makes everything ugly, doesn't it?

Comment: ...and the basic javascript code to select an item based on string matching is so incredibly elegant? ;)

Comment: No luck, but thanks for the input! And jQuery isn't too ugly, in my opinion. I think $() is much better than querySelector() or document.getElement...

Comment: @ggwicz hmm ... strange ... you know it's also case sensitive, right?  That's the only other thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You could try chaining two calls together.

http://jsfiddle.net/d2emb/